# How to refresh page only once so you can restore some variables onto the page?

Tags: javascript, reload

Currently, I am using a `location.reload(true)` to reload the page and then I have a function `store()` which should take the `localStorage.setItem('...')` and place it into an `<output id="...">` after the page has reloaded.
The issue is (I believe) that the `location.reload(true)` is on an infinite loop and therefore when my `store()` function is used, it wipes that immediately too. I think this because if I click the store button, the saved value flashes where it should be...
So the question is: how can I reload the page ONLY ONCE so that the store function will work?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why reload the page at all? Just put the value in the output directly.

Comment: you can add a parameter in the url or cookie who store the number of time the page has been reloaded. if it's more than 1 you don't do location.reload(à

Answer (score 0):

Put this in `<head>` tag of your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(localStorage.getItem('PageIsReloaded')!=null && localStorage.getItem('PageIsReloaded')=='true')
    {
       localStorage.setItem('PageIsReloaded',true);
       location.reload(true);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This seems to remove other parts of my program, for example the select list where you chose a starting budget.
The code for this is as follows:
'function listbudgetstart() {
 var zero = 0;
 var maxi = 500;
 var budgoptions = "<options value='0'>select</option>";
 for (var i = zero; i <= maxi; i= i+50){
  budgoptions += "<option value='"+i+"'>"+i+"</option>"}
  document.getElementById("start1").innerHTML= budgoptions; }'

Comment: This code 'only job is to make sure to location.reload(true) runs only once.
The rest of problems are other parts of your code issue's.

Comment: The program doesn't work when I enter your code but does when I remove it again...

Comment: Do you enclose  it with script tag??